# incrementing css values sequentially to right in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
p_relative1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.p_relative2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top:  20px;
}

.p_relative3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top:  40px;
}

.p_relative4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 40px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p class="p_relative1">relative1</p>
<p class="p_relative2">relative2</p>
<p class="p_relative3">relative3</p>
<p class="p_relative4">relative4</p>
```

I want to sequentially add more p elements-say (relative5, relative6,relative7 and so on) by incrementing my `left` value by 10 px , is there a way to do, I read in CSS we can't do something like that, please advise any workarounds.

Comment: With *sequentually add more elements* you mean add them through JavaScript or by writing more HTML?

Comment: only css and html

Comment: Okay, well that's indeed not possible with CSS. You could use something like [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) to generate your CSS within a loop. For example, with Sass you can [loop](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for) from 1 to the number of elements that you want and generate a class for each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible with only HTML and CSS, but you can use [CSS-Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

```css
.p_relative {
  position: relative;
  left: calc(10px + (var(--offset) * 1px));
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p class="p_relative" style="--offset: 10">relative1</p>
<p class="p_relative" style="--offset: 20">relative2</p>
<p class="p_relative" style="--offset: 30">relative3</p>
<p class="p_relative" style="--offset: 40">relative4</p>
```

Comment: works and accepted